# Changing shape of UIView in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to change the shape of the UIView from rectangular
to triangular in Xcode 5?

Comment: @MertBuran what does this have to do with `xcode` or `xcode5`?

Comment: I thought it's about Interface Builder, I might misunderstand the question but I'm pretty sure "xcode5" is not one of the most suitable tags here.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you mean interface builder? No. You can do it a few ways in code.  Override drawInRect (preferred) OR create the view on photoshop (quick and dirty) and bring it as an image. Then set the background as clear and add the imageview to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  it's dirty but i think i will take your advice and stick with the photoshop for this task.